# How to register/gather parent and child classes?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I am looking for a good way to auto hook child classes from a parent class in WordPress.

I'm creating a plugin with some different templates and I would like to gather all the child template classes in an array so I can list them.

```
class template {
    // Methods
}

class name1 extends template {
    // Methods
}

class name2 extends template {
    // Methods
}

class name3 extends template {
    // Methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `get_declared_classes()` ([link to docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php)).

Then iterate the result and see which of the returned classes is a a children of your `template` class.

E.g.:

// given these classes

```php
class father {}
class child1 extends father {}
class child2 extends father {}
class child3 extends father {}
class notMe {}
```

// you could have an utility function like this

```php
function getChildrenOf(string $parentClass): array {

    if (!class_exists($parentClass)) {
       return [];
    }

    $classes = array_filter(get_declared_classes(), function($class) use($parentClass) {

        return is_a($class, $parentClass, true);
    });

    return $classes;
}
```

// which you could use like this

```php
$childrenClasses = getChildrenOf(father::class);

var_dump($childrenClasses);
```

You can see it all working together [here](https://3v4l.org/lPd6W).

Comment: Thank you so much. Code seems perfect. I'll test it out.

Comment: There were a couple of bugs, @FilipVanReeth. I updated the answer after testing it.

Comment: thanks. I'm on holiday this week. Thanks for the code update. I'm quite sure it will work. I'll get back to you after my test ;-)